# Docker Container not saving state

Tags: docker, server, export, jira, state

> As I can't upvote the solution myself, thank you **snahor** for
>   pointing it out! When one can read..  
>   The Dockerfile clearly states you have to persist a volume on your local machine. 
>   As a sidenote for future encounters with this problem. ***There are known issues with Docker for Windows and Volumes. Setting it all up from a Linux Shell will sidestep those.*** *(at least it did for me)*

as I was trying to make several parts of a testing framework more portable one of which happens to be accessing Jira I encountered the following problem with the Jira Container:

I ended up using this image from Dockerhub [cptactionhanks Jira](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/) which worked like a charm. 
I tried accessing the server with our framework which also worked, then proceeded to try and save the container.

When I `export` or `commit` a .tar file from the container *(or `save` from image)* and attempt to run that image afterwards, I always end up back in the *server-configuration*, whereas when I `stop/start` my original container the server is up and running.
Im a bit at a loss to why it won't let me save state here?

Edit: As the question seems unclear heres what I did (each of these seperately)
*Started up the image like so:*

```
docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest
```

*Accessed jira in the browser at http://localhost:8080 and set up the server.*
*Tried saving state:*

```
docker commit [containerID] commited_img
docker export -o exported_img.tar [containerID]
docker save -o saved_img.tar [imageID]
```

*Tried accessing state:*

```
docker run --publish 8080:8080 commited_img
docker import exported_img.tar jira_exp_img    //running the img afterwards
docker load -i saved_img.tar                  //running the img afterwards
```

*leave bitemarks in the table as it refuses to save state again and again*

Let me apologize in advance if this should be obvious since Im using Docker for nearly 2 days ..

random musing:
I set up the server with its own standard database, any chance this is conflicting on startup?

Comment: I'm kinda confused. Could you write all the commands you used?

Comment: Edited with some more information (hopefully..)

Comment: I think you need to persist the volumes, check the Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/~/dockerfile/.

Comment: I reckon that is it, you sir are a genius (I guess).
As I see it I'll just have to run docker cp [containerID] "srcpath" "tarpath"then put them in a local volume and use it to run the image?

Comment: Do you really need to create an image? If you persist the volumes the data will stay there after stopping/removing the container https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume

Comment: You are of course right, sorry if I seem slow, picking it up as I go along. It works by the way, thank you very much! Would love to upvote but alas I cant yet D:

Comment: Don't worry, docker may be confusing at first but you will master it soon. Just one suggestion, check docker-compose, it is friendlier and easier than using plain docker commands.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `docker save` instead `export` or `commit`?
It should create a .tar file which can be imported with `docker load`

Comment: Several times unfortunately, only ever gets me back to the secure/SetupMode!default.jspa routine :S Sorry I should have included that in the original post as well   (does *save* even save state of a Container? As I understood it, save would only apply changes to the image runtime? Either way didnt work :( )
Thanks for your answer though!